# How to add a dynamic, server-fetched default value to a Zod-validated React Hook Form?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, supabase, zod

I have a React Hook form with validation and default values from Zod. I am using Supabase as my DB and Auth. How can I set the default value of userId to be current user's id? User state is inside the component, which does not have access to defaultValues defined outside.

Code:

````
// This can come from your database or API.
const defaultValues: Partial<ProfileFormValues> = {
  can_share: true,
  userId: ___   <---- THE VALUE I WANT TO BE AUTOMATICALLY SET TO CURRENT USERID
};

export default function Page() {
  // TODO: redirect if no user detected
  // FIXME: no user fetched

  const [user, setUser] = useState<any>();
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkIsUser = async () => {
      const res = await fetch('/api/get-user', { method: 'GET' });
      const data = res.status;
      setUser(data);
      console.log(user);
    };
    checkIsUser();
  }, []);

  console.log(user);
  if (!user) {
    redirect('/login');
  }
  const [url, setUrl] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const form = useForm<ProfileFormValues>({
    resolver: zodResolver(profileFormSchema),
    defaultValues,
    mode: 'onChange',
  });

  async function onSubmit(data: ProfileFormValues) {
    const res = await fetch('/api/create', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }).then(async (res) => {
      const json = await res.json();
      if (json.status === 201) {
        toast.success('Template created!');
        console.log(json);
        setUrl(json.data);
      }
    });
  }
  const handleCopy = () => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(
      `WEBSITE`
    );
    toast.success('Copied to clipboard.');
  };```
````

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Passing in dynamic data in `defaultValues` does not work.

In the zod documentation, [zod documentation](https://www.react-hook-form.com/api/useform/#values)

You can add your reactive data inside the `values` attribute.
Like this below.

```
  const defaultValues: Partial<ProfileFormValues> = {
    can_share: true,
    userId: ''
  };

  const values: Partial<ProfileFormValues> = {
    can_share: true,
    userId: // Your variable data can come here
  };

  const form = useForm<ProfileFormValues>({
    resolver: zodResolver(profileFormSchema),
    defaultValues,
    mode: 'onChange',
    values
  });
```

Doing this change will automatically update your form values after data is fetched.